# GAE Task Queue: Task not running/outputting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I've started using the task queue to schedule a time-intensive task to run in the background. The task I want to run is in the URL '/test', and the URL I am using to schedule the task is '/bgtest'. Here is the handler for '/bgtest':

```
class RunTestAsBackgroundProcess(BaseHandler):
def get_secure(self):
    taskqueue.add(url='/test', method='GET')
    logging.debug("Task added to queue")
    return
```

The '/test' task outputs data to the logs, and when I visit /test normally it executes, finishes and I can find the results in the logs. However, when I run /bgtest I see nothing in the logs except the "Task added to queue" message from the above function. Strangely, in the Task Queue in the admin console it says that a task has run in the last minute but doesn't give me any details about it. Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to explain the code, BaseHandler is a superclass I use to check the user is logged in to Facebook, and get_secure() is the method called after the superclass' get() method.

EDIT: /test runs this class:

```
class CalculateTestAllocations(BaseHandler):
def get_secure(self):
    dbuser = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE fbid = :1", self.user['uid'])[0]
    if (dbuser.isadmin != True):
        self.redirect('/')

    #test data
    drivers = []
    passengers = []

    drivers.append(allocation.Driver("01", allocation.Location(51.440958, -2.576318), 3, 1000)) # coming from Bristol
    drivers.append(allocation.Driver("02", allocation.Location(55.935628, -3.285044), 3, 1000)) # coming from Edinburgh

    passengers.append(allocation.Passenger("03", allocation.Location(51.483193, -3.208187), 1000)) # coming from Cardiff
    passengers.append(allocation.Passenger("04", allocation.Location(52.469263, -1.860303), 1000)) # coming from Birmingham
    passengers.append(allocation.Passenger("05", allocation.Location(53.783703, -1.541841), 1000)) # coming from Leeds
    passengers.append(allocation.Passenger("06", allocation.Location(54.973994, -1.636391), 1000)) # coming from Newcastle

    logging.debug("Running allocation engine now (GET)")

    alloc = allocation.Allocation()
    alloc.buildProblem(drivers, passengers, allocation.Location(52.951923, -1.169967)) # destination at Nottingham
    alloc.solveAndOutput()
```

This populates a set of test data for my allocation algorithm (which takes in a set of drivers and passengers and calculates the optimum route for them) and then tells the algorithm to run. The stuff sent to the log is contained in the allocation.solveAndOutput() method, which does this:

```
def solveAndOutput(self):
    routes = self.solveProblem()
    logging.warn("Num routes: "+str(len(routes)))
    logging.warn("Length of first route: "+str(len(routes[0])))
    for route in routes:
        print self.getStaticMapAddress(route)
        logging.debug(self.getStaticMapAddress(route))
```

As I said, if I just run /test I get these outputs, but if I run /bgtest nothing happens but the task queue says it ran something in the past minute.

Comment: What do you see in the logs if you set them to show everything? Is there a corresponding log entry for `/test`? What is its status code?

Comment: When I run /test I get status code 200, and all the log entries I have set for /test to output. When I run /bgtest I don't get any of the log entries I get with /test

Comment: What does /test do? Please, add that part of code.

Comment: @benwad Did you set the logs to 'all requests'? What shows up in the logs?

Comment: @Nick switched to 'all requests' and saw that when I ran /bgtest it outputted the "Task added to queue" message, then I see it made a request to /test with a 200 status, but nothing logged. Plus it says it only took 3ms, whereas when I run /test straight out it takes up to 1000ms.

Comment: @benwad Then the problem is not that your task is not being enqueued - it's that it's executing and not logging anything. See my answer below, and add more diagnostic logging to your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `/test` script is fetching from what I can only presume is a session, and then redirecting based on that. That's obviously not going to work in a Task Queue task - there is no user, and hence no session.

Comment: Sorted it. You were right - I just needed to remove anything that requires a user, i.e. that BaseHandler inheritance.